# Easy to Use Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I am trying to get a nice paginator to work but I'm having trouble with getting the upcoming/middle numbers to work properly.

The goal is to show the first and last 5 pages of a result set regardless of what page your on, but these first and last 5 can only show if there are enough pages to allow it.

The pagination would look something like this: << 1 2 3 4 5 - 12 **13** 14 - 78 79 80 81 82 >>

With only a few pages: << 1 **2** 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 >>

And how to avoid this?: << 1 2 3 4 5 - 5 **6** 7 - 7 8 9 10 11 >>

My code so far is:

```
function pagination_links($page, $num_rows, $results_per_page, $each_direction = 3) 
{ 
$total_pages = $num_rows ? ceil($num_rows / $results_per_page) : 1 ; 
if($total_pages < 2) 
{ 
    return null; 
} 
$page = ((is_numeric($page)) && ($page >= 1) && ($page <= $total_pages)) ? (int)$page : 1 ; 
$output = null; 
if($page > 1) 
{ 
    $output .= '<div class="pageBtn"><<</div>' ; 
}
else
{
    $output .= '<div class="pageBtnDis"><<</div>' ;
}

for($i=1;$i<$total_pages;$i++)
{
     if($page != $i) 
    { 
        $output .= '<div class="pageBtn">' . $i . '</div>' ; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $output .= '<div class="pageBtnSet">' . $i . '</div>' ;
    }
    if($i > 4)
    {
        break ;
    }
}

for($i = $page - $each_direction; $i <= $page + $each_direction; $i++) 
{ 
    if(($i > 5) && ($i <= $total_pages-5)) 
    { 
        if($page != $i) 
        { 
            $output .= '<div class="pageBtn">' . $i . '</div>' ; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $output .= '<div class="pageBtnSet">' . $i . '</div>' ;
        } 
    } 
}

for($i = $total_pages-5;$i<$total_pages;$i++) {
    if($page != $i) 
        { 
            $output .= '<div class="pageBtn">' . $i . '</div>' ; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $output .= '<div class="pageBtnSet">' . $i . '</div>' ;
        } 
}
if($page < $total_pages) 
{ 
    $output .= '<div class="pageBtn">>></div>' ; 
}
else
{
    $output .= '<div class="pageBtnDis">>></div>' ;
}
return $output ;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the current best solution is to use [Digg Style Pagination Class](http://mis-algoritmos.com/digg-style-pagination-class). It greatly simplifies the creation and styling of your pagination markup.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pager PEAR class](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager/) is highly customizable and I've had a lot of success with it.

Comment: PEAR is a lost cause. It is bloated and full of dependencies. Exactly what Object Oriented code should not be. Serious programmers do not use PEAR which has gone pear shape over the years. You can write your own pager in 30 minutes flat if you know how to write code. Tip: the pager should never produce HTML code. It should instead put the result of its calculations into an array and let another class produce the HTML. That's a good starting point.

Comment: @JGEstiot Yeah, no one uses PEAR anymore. This is a three year old answer - these days I'd advise someone use a framework like Laravel with pagination built-in.

Comment: I wouldn't touch Laravel. For 99% of projects, it is a complete overkill.

Comment: @JGEstiot I'd disagree entirely, but there are plenty of other frameworks to pick from.